# Disallow php script to change the php_value set in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to disable php changing the value using ini_set('display_errors ', 0) when I have defined this in .htaccess file?

php_value display_errors 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use `php_admin_value` directive in virtual host, this cannot be overwritten later in PHP scripts.

EDIT:
My bad, this can be used only in virtual host in Apache.